# Connection disconnected Server returned an error on close: Connection closed with an error. ArgumentNullException Value cannot be null (Parameter key)

Tags: asp.net, angular, signalr, user-presence

I am trying to implement signalR to see who of my users are currently connected. i get connected then immediately after I get an error saying that the connection disconnected:

[image: Error]

This is what I have got :

A "presence hub" :

```
public class PresenceHub : Hub   
    {
        private readonly PresenceTracker _tracker;

        public PresenceHub(PresenceTracker tracker)
        {
            _tracker = tracker;
        }
        public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
        {
            await _tracker.UserConnected(Context.User.GetUsername(), Context.ConnectionId);
            await Clients.Others.SendAsync("UserIsOnline", Context.User.GetUsername());

            var currentUsers = await _tracker.GetOnlineUsers();
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("GetOnlineUsers", currentUsers);
        }

        public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
        {
            await _tracker.UserDisconnected(Context.User.GetUsername(), Context.ConnectionId);

            await Clients.Others.SendAsync("UserIsOffline", Context.User.GetUsername());

            var currentUsers = await _tracker.GetOnlineUsers();
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("GetOnlineUsers", currentUsers);

            await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
        }
    }
```

A "presence tracker" to track the connected users :

```
public class PresenceTracker
    {
        private static readonly Dictionary<string, List<string>> OnlineUsers = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

        public Task UserConnected(string username, string connectionId)
        {
            lock (OnlineUsers)
            {
                if (OnlineUsers.ContainsKey(username))
                {
                    OnlineUsers[username].Add(connectionId);
                }
                else
                {
                    OnlineUsers.Add(username, new List<string>{ connectionId });
                }
            }

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public Task UserDisconnected(string username, string connectionId)
        {
            lock (OnlineUsers)
            {
                if(!OnlineUsers.ContainsKey(username)) return Task.CompletedTask;

                OnlineUsers[username].Remove(connectionId);

                if (OnlineUsers[username].Count == 0)
                {
                    OnlineUsers.Remove(username);
                }
            }

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public Task<string[]> GetOnlineUsers()
        {
            string[] onlineUsers;
            lock (OnlineUsers)
            {
                onlineUsers = OnlineUsers.OrderBy(k => k.Key).Select(k => k.Key).ToArray();
            }

            return Task.FromResult(onlineUsers);
        } 
    }
}
```

The addAuthentication service :

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Token:Key"])),
            ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Token:Issuer"],
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            ValidateAudience = false
        };

        options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
        {
            OnMessageReceived = context =>
            {
                var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];

                var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken) && path.StartsWithSegments("hubs"))
                {
                    context.Token = accessToken;
                }

                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        };
    });
```

This is my service for the presence :

```
createHubConnection(user: User) {
    this.hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl(this.hubUrl + 'presence', {
        accessTokenFactory: () => user.token,
      })
      .withAutomaticReconnect()
      .build()
  
    this.hubConnection.start().then(() => {console.log("connection to hub successful") }).catch(error => console.log(error));

    this.hubConnection.on('UserIsOnline', username => {
      this.toastr.info(username + " has connected");
    })

    this.hubConnection.on('UserIsOffline', username => {
      this.toastr.info(username + " has disconnected");
    })

    this.hubConnection.on('GetOnlineUsers ', usernames => {
      this.onlineUsersSource.next(usernames);
    })
  }

  stopHubConnection() {
    this.hubConnection?.stop().catch(error => console.log(error));
  }
```

I have tried multiple things amongst which are these middlewares :

```
app.UseCors(builder =>
{
    builder.WithOrigins("https://localhost:4200")
           .AllowCredentials()
           .AllowAnyMethod()
           .AllowAnyHeader();
});

app.MapHub<PresenceHub>("/hubs/presence");
app.UseWebSockets();

builder.Services.AddSignalR(o =>
{
    o.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
    o.MaximumReceiveMessageSize = 102400000;
});

builder.Services.AddSingleton<PresenceTracker>();
```

Comment: `Context.User` is likely null, you didn't add the auth middleware, only the services. Also, you should turn on nullability, then the compiler would tell you what might be null in your code.

Comment: Yes you are rigth, Context.User is null. But can I fix it ?

Comment: Yes, use authentication.

Comment: But Besides adding app.UseAuthentication() and app.UseAuthorization() what else is there to do ?